# Can't install .NET 4.8 (.NET Framework 4.8) on hyperV server core 2012

Tags: .net-4.8

My backup software requires .net 4.8 and I have .net 4.7 installed on hyperV server core host.

I am unable to install .net 4.8 on core.  It will run and have a pop up asking if its ok.  Click ok then the window disappears and im back at the command prompt.
There is no gui its server core (no windows).

I tried the web version and the standalone all OS version of .net 4.8.   Not sure if it can be done.  Can anyone with server 2012 core confirm?

Thanks.

Install .net 4.8 on server 2012 core

Expected it to be installed.

Verified it was not by check registry and also by installing software than needs 4.8 both confirm im on 4.7 still.

Comment: Have you consulted https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/microsoft-net-framework-4-8-for-windows-server-2012-ffc7ea09-24e4-76ce-648f-290617580544?

Comment: This probably belongs on ServerFault.com but  anyway... did you try running the installer in quiet mode? https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/installing-net-framework-48-on-windows-server-2019/625606

Comment: Thanks!  silent mode  /q worked.  No echo so it just sat there then rebooted the server.  Its on 4.8 hyperV 2012 core.   ndp48-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe /q